# Entity Framework - search on encrypted columns

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have this table:

```
 public class Person
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [Encrypted]
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

and this attribute:

```
public class EncryptedAttribute: Attribute { }
```

Now, I want every property with this Encrypted attribute will be saved with the encrypted value. but when I want to do query using LINQ I don't want to manipulate the search value. example:

```
string searchTerm = "Sean";
// I want to search like this
var results = ctx.Persons.where(p => p.Name == searchTerm).ToList();
//and not like this
// var results = ctx.Persons.where(p => p.Name == EncryptMethod(searchTerm)).ToList();
```

is it posible to do something like this?

thanks.